# How to fetch MULTI-LEVELS of related tables in EntityFramework after an Insert?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

I have a typical 1-M-1 relationship; to keep it simple, lets deal with 3 tables only, but my real problem is more complex.

```
UsersTbl --< UserMenusTbl >-- MenusRefTbl
```

The MenusRefTbl is a reference table, which is pretty much static. To create a new user, I load up data into a **newUser** Parent Entity (class UsersTbl), and its child navigation property (class UsersMenuTbl).

Then I call

```
var savedUserEntity = dbCtx.UsersTbl.Add(newUser);
int rowsAffected = dbCtx.SaveChanges();
```

This inserts data in both Parent and Child table (UsersTbl, UserMenusTbl), and generates any @@identity primary/foreign keys in both tables automatically; In effect, the LHS variable **`savedUserEntity`** is now refreshed to contain the auto-generated identities.
However, the navigation property for the 3rd table (MenusRefTbl) remains null; 
For example,

```
savedUserEntity.UserMenusTbl.MenusRefTbl = null;
```

How do I fetch the 3rd TABLE data into my object savedUserEntity ?

I've seen a few methods like .Reload(), .LoadAsync() but they don't seem to work with navigation properties (multi-levels of related tables), or apply in my case.

So am I stuck with re-issuing a new query from scratch using a new context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i have done using the same context:

```
var savedUserEntity = dbCtx.UsersTbl.Add(newUser);
int rowsAffected = dbCtx.SaveChanges();
rtnUserEntity = dbCtx.UsersTbl
            .Include(um => um.UserMenusTbl.Select(m => m.MenusRefTbl))
            .Where(u => u.userID == savedUserEntity.userID) //identity after Save
            .Single(); //rtn single record
```